# Can I implement Header authorization from BasicAuth?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring and I implemented BasicAuth using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=egXtoL5Kg08&t). Is there any way that I can implement authorization header instead of BasicAuth painlessly? Is configuring SecurityConfig enough? I am building a web service.
This is my SecurityConfig if it helps

```
package com.example.infobip.config;

import com.example.infobip.IUrlService;
import com.example.infobip.repositories.UsersRepository;
import com.example.infobip.service.CustomUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UsersRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return charSequence.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
                http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/statistic/**", "/register").authenticated()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "header authorization"? Do you want to build a web application or a web service?

Comment: @MattKe I am building web service. I am not sure, since I am very new to Spring, it says in my assignment that in POST request header i have to set up Authorization header and identify user

Comment: What should be transferred in the Authorization header? When building a web service, you usually use an access token to identify the user.

Comment: @MattKe I guess username and password which is used for authentication. I tried [this](http://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring) but after that I get 403 error

Answer (score 0):

I finally made it! I was supposed to add .httpBasicAuth() after http.csrf().disable(). Also, [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/how-to-use-resttemplate-with-basic-authentication-in-spring) helps a lot.